# what does one million word represent in the question below?

Tags: computer-architecture

An Associated cache and one million word main memory are divided into 256 word blocks. How many blocks are there?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? Do you really need us to do arithmetic for you?

Comment: A word is a fixed-size string of bits, generally larger than a byte, which is 8-bits.  The exact size is architecture-dependent, and might be 16-bits, 32-bits or 64-bits.  Older computers were not [byte oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_addressing), and often used unusual word sizes (e.g. 12, 18, 36), which made them harder to compare regarding memory size.  Anyway, this question can be answered without knowing the specific size of the word. In computer architecture, "million" will mean [mega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega-#Computing), so 2^20.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ONE MILLION WORD = 2^20 words, 
we have, size of main memory = 2^20 words

Now, block size = 256 = 2^8 words

Number of blocks in Main Memory = 2^20/(2^8) = 2^12